# Progress bar is not showing on AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm Trying to show a Progress dialog while my listView(to show all of applications on device) is being loaded.

but It's not showing up.

here is My main activity class and what I have tried.

what can the problem be?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }


}


ProgressDialog dlg;
private class Updator extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
{ 
    public Updator()
    {
        dlg = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dlg.setMessage("Text");
        dlg.setTitle("Title");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        dlg.show();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() 
            {
                PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
                List<ApplicationInfo> apps = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
                ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> installedApp = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();


                for(ApplicationInfo app : apps) 
                {
                    installedApp.add(app);
                }

                ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);


                //custom list is a class to create a custom list view.
                //it also will load application icons into list(which needs time)
                CustomList adapter = new CustomList(MainActivity.this, installedApp);

                TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                t.setText(installedApp.size());

                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
                    {
                       //some things app will do
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return (null);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) 
    {

        dlg.dismiss();
    }
}


public void onBtnClick(View v)
{
    new Updator().execute();
}
```

}

Comment: You don't need runOnUiThread in doInBackground

Comment: @Raghunandan On that case I will got error on 'lv.setAdapter(adapter);'

Comment: doInBackground is supposed to be for background operation. You have onPostExecute where you can do the ui operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably change your asynctask to look something like this:

```
private class Updator extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>> {

public Updator()
{
    dlg = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    dlg.setMessage("Text");
    dlg.setTitle("Title");
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    dlg.show();
}

@Override
protected ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> doInBackground(Void... params) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> apps = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
    ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> installedApp = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();


    for(ApplicationInfo app : apps)
    {
        installedApp.add(app);
    }

    return installedApp;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> installedApps) {
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    //custom list is a class to create a custom list view.
    //it also will load application icons into list(which needs time)
    CustomList adapter = new CustomList(MainActivity.this, installedApp);

    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    t.setText(installedApp.size());

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            //some things app will do
        }
    });

    dlg.dismiss();
}
}
```

If you perform all the calculation in doInBackground on the main thread it won't show the spinner.
It is, as pointed out in some of the comments, better to do the calculations in the background and then send that information to onPostExecute.